# how to Connection sqlite db on vuenative app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

I need connection to SQLite db on vueNative but I do not know what to do. Can you help me? How to connect to SQLite db on vueNative app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the app without --no-crna option ,then you could go through https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite or else you can try https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage